# Overwriting Pixels in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have an image that I am trying to replace pixels with some arbitrary color(let's say blue). How can I do this with an array. For example my image is:

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
p q r s t
u v w x y
```

And I want to change the color of columns 3,2,3,4,3 so that my image becomes something like

```
a b c * e
f g * i j
k l m * o
p q r s *
u v w * y
```

where the * is the replaced pixel with blue. How can one do that?

Comment: `X[0,3] = blue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not specify any restrictions, I assume any tool is fine, so I suggest using [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/). (Install with `pip install Pillow`)

Say your image is named `image.png` then you can loop through the pixels you want to edit and set the color at each position to the desired color.

```py
from PIL import Image

replacement_color = (0, 0, 255)
columns = [3, 2, 3, 4, 3]
positions = [(x, y) for y, x in enumerate(columns)]

image = Image.open('image.png')
pixels = image.load()

for (x, y) in positions:
    pixels[x, y] = replacement_color

image.show() # or image.save('transformed_image.png')
```

Be warned that this is approach of accessing and editing individual pixels can be very slow.

---

**EDIT:**

Using a boolean numpy array as a mask to identify the right pixels you can also use

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('image.png')
image_array = np.array(image)

# Just an example mask
diagonal = np.eye(image_array.shape[0], image_array.shape[1])
mask = diagonal == 1

image_array[mask] = [0, 0, 255, 0] # RGBA

altered_image = Image.fromarray(image_array)
altered_image.save('altered_image.png')
```

(Adapted from [this guide](https://www.pythoninformer.com/python-libraries/numpy/numpy-and-images/))

I am not sure, if the performance is better though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I should have clarified that I was trying to implement it using numpy arrays. I am able to create a boolent mask to basically mark those pixels as False and remove them to reshape the array but for the life of me, I can;t seem to figure out how to change the values of the pixels to a certain color.

Comment: @MrJonesIsCountingCrows Why do you say you are reshaping the array? It is 5x5 when you start and 5x5 afterwards!

Comment: I am learning about seam carving so at the end I need to reduce the image so I am reshaping the array. So after every time a vertical seam is removed, the image gets reduced by one pixel in every row. I can do the carving fine. But before I carve, I also want to visualize what seams I am removing and hence, I want to color the pixels to visually see it

Comment: I think I juts figured it out using the iteration method that @BurningKarl suggested.The computation time is a lot but i will worry about performance later